# Julia: Broadcasting Functions with Keyword Arguments

Tags: function, julia

Suppose we have a composite type:

```
mutable struct MyType{TF<:AbstractFloat, TI<:Integer}
a::TF
b::TF
end
```

We define a constructor

```
function MyType(a; b = 1.0)
    return MyType(a, b)
end
```

I can broadcast `MyType` over an array of `a`'s, but how can I do that for `b`'s?

I tried to do

```
MyType.([1.0, 2.0, 3.0]; [:b, 1.0, :b, 2.0, :b, 3.0,])
```

But, this does not work.

Note that the above example is totally artificial. In reality, I have a composite type that takes in many fields, many of which are constructed using keyword arguments, and I only want to change a few of them into different values stored in an array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with dot-notation, however, you can manually construct the broadcast call:

```
julia> struct Foo
           a::Int
           b::Int
           Foo(a; b = 1) = new(a, b)
       end

julia> broadcast((x, y) -> Foo(x, b = y), [1,2,3], [4,5,6])
3-element Array{Foo,1}:
 Foo(1, 4)
 Foo(2, 5)
 Foo(3, 6)

julia> broadcast((x, y) -> Foo(x; y), [1,2,3], [:b=>4,:b=>5,:b=>6])
3-element Array{Foo,1}:
 Foo(1, 4)
 Foo(2, 5)
 Foo(3, 6)
```

Comment: `f.(args...)` is equivalent to `broadcast(f, args...)`. You are wrapping your function in an anonymous function and can also be done with the dot-syntax for broadcasting: `((x, y) -> Foo(x, b=y).([1,2,3], [4,5,6])`