# Julia - Is it possible to do a vectorized call on a struct or function by a keyword argument?

Tags: julia

Is it possible to do an efficient and elegant vectorized call on a function or struct by a single (or few) keyword arguments?
Something like this

```
F(;x=10, y=20) = y + x

Base.@kwdef struct S
    x = 10
    y = 20
end

F.(y=1:20) # doesn't work
S.(y=1:20) # doesn't work
```

PS. I know I can do this in a for loop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Julia: Broadcasting Functions with Keyword Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48738016/julia-broadcasting-functions-with-keyword-arguments)

Comment: And there is also a pull request on github. https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/34737

Comment: That's an issue, not a pull request... and it's unlikely to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use anonymous function as a wrapper

```
julia> F(; x = 10, y = 10) = x + y
julia> (y -> F(y = y)).(1:20)
20-element Vector{Int64}:
 11
 12

julia> Base.@kwdef struct S
           x = 10
           y = 20
       end

julia> (y -> S(y = y)).(1:20)
20-element Vector{S}:
 S(10, 1)
 S(10, 2)
 S(10, 3)
```